# I found ID of account merge and the lumens are missing

Tags: lumens

this is so strange and my lumens are missing
https://horizon.stellar.org/operations/67678436792995841

Answer (score 5):

GAX3BRBNB5WTJ2GNEFFH7A4CZKT2FORYABDDBZR5FIIT3P7FLS2EFOZZ is "invitesHot"

You got lumens from an SDF invite, and the invite email or website (don't remember which) says that you have to perform a transaction on the account within a certain number of days, or the funds will be reclaimed.

You didn't, so the funds got reclaimed.